# Merge 3 arrays in to one

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a array like following Array i want to merge that array with another 2 arrays. i have tried with array merge function and it failed can you suggest any other way.

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_name] => mem_goup_name
            [table_name] => membership_group
            [field_id] => 15
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_name] => mem_group_description
            [table_name] => membership_group
            [field_id] => 17
        )


)
```

And I want to set these 2 arrays to that former array

```
Array
(
    [fiter_15] => 5
    [fiter_17] => 2
)
Array
(
    [operator_15] => 3
    [operator_17] => 1
)
```

which means like this, (the key with the number must equal to the field_id).

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_name] => mem_goup_name
            [table_name] => membership_group
            [field_id] => 15,
            [fiter_15] => 5,
            [operator_15] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [field_name] => mem_group_description
            [table_name] => membership_group
            [field_id] => 17,
            [fiter_17] => 2,
            [operator_17] => 1
        )
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$operator = array(); 
$filter = array(); 
$field_ids = array();

 foreach ($fitered_values as $key => $value) { 

  if (strpos($key, 'operator_') !== false) {
  $operator[$key] = $value; 
  }

  if (strpos($key, 'fiter_') !== false) {
  $filter[$key] = $value; 
  } 

  if (strpos($key, 'field_ids_') !== false) { 
  $field_ids[$key] = $value; 
  } 

}
```

Comment: Have you tried any solutions?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed    $operator = array();
        $filter = array();
        $field_ids = array();

        foreach ($fitered_values as $key => $value)
        {
            if (strpos($key, 'operator_') !== false)
            {
                $operator[$key] = $value;
            }

            if (strpos($key, 'fiter_') !== false)
            {
                $filter[$key] = $value;
            }
            if (strpos($key, 'field_ids_') !== false)
            {
                $field_ids[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

Comment: Please edit your question with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop the first array and use preg_grep to find the keys.
I grep the array_keys of array2 and the output is intersected to get the array items.
Then I merge it in to the main array1.

```
$arr2 = array_merge($filter, $operator);

foreach($arr1 as $key => $item){
    $temp = preg_grep("/.*_" . $item['field_id'] . "/", Array_keys($arr2));
    $arr1[$key] = array_merge($arr1[$key] , array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip($temp)));
}
var_dump($arr1);
```

https://3v4l.org/3Inbb

Also, why do you have two accounts?
[filter array by string and separate in to 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947631/filter-array-by-string-and-separate-in-to-2-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below and let me know if it works for you.

```
$arr1 = array(
            0 => (object)array
            (
                'field_name' => 'mem_goup_name',
                'table_name' => 'membership_group',
                'field_id' => 15
            ),
            1 => (object)array
            (
                'field_name' => 'mem_group_description',
                'table_name' => 'membership_group',
                'field_id' => 17
            )
        );


$arr2 = array
(
    'fiter_15' => 5,
    'fiter_17' => 2
);
$arr3 = array
(
    'operator_15' => 3,
    'operator_17' => 1
);

foreach( $arr1 as $key => $value )
{
    $key1= 'filter_'.$value->field_id;
    $key2 = 'operator_'.$value->field_id;
    $arr1[$key]->$key1 = $arr2['fiter_'.$value->field_id];
    $arr1[$key]->$key2 = $arr3['operator_'.$value->field_id];
}
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: Preeti answers on SO should include what the answer does and not only "try this".

Comment: This code may give an notice that an array item does not exist if 'field_id' from the first array does not exist in the other two.