# How to separate a php array items by prefix

Tags: php, arrays

I want to separate a PHP array when they have a common prefix.

```
$data = ['status.1', 'status.2', 'status.3',
         'country.244', 'country.24', 'country.845',
         'pm.4', 'pm.9', 'pm.6'];
```

I want each of them in separate variables like `$status, $countries, $pms` which will contain:

```
$status = [1,2,3];
$country = [244, 24, 845]
$pms = [4,9,6]
```

My Current code is taking 1.5 seconds to group them:

```
$statuses = [];
$countries = [];
$pms = [];
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($data as $item){
    if(strpos($item, 'status.') !== false){
        $statuses[]= substr($item,7);
    }

    if(strpos($item, 'country.') !== false){
        $countries[]= substr($item,8);
    }

    if(strpos($item, 'pm.') !== false){
        $pms[]= substr($item,3);
    }
}
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
print_r($time_elapsed_secs);
```

I want to know if is there any faster way to do this

Comment: Will you have only those 3 prefix or it is dynamic prefixs?

Comment: You can use asort($data) to improve loop performance

Comment: I will have 5 prefixes like status, country, pm, study type and date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you results for more dynamic prefixs - first explode with the delimiter and then insert by the key to result array.

For separating the value you can use: [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Consider the following code:

```
$data = array('status.1','status.2','status.3', 'country.244', 'country.24', 'country.845', 'pm.4','pm.9', 'pm.6');

$res = array();
foreach($data as $elem) {
    list($key,$val) = explode(".", $elem, 2);
    $res[$key][] = $val;

}
extract($res); // this will separate to var with the prefix name

echo "Status is: " . print_r($status); // will output array of ["1","2","3"]
```

This snippet took less the 0.001 second...

Thanks @mickmackusa for the simplification

Answer (score 3):

Add `continue` to each of the `if`'s, so if it's one of them, it won't then run the other ones... not really needed in the last one as obviously the loops starts again anyway.  Should save a tiny bit of time, but doubt it'll be as much as you probably want to save.

```
foreach($data as $item){
    if(strpos($item, 'status.') !== false){
        $statuses[]= substr($item,7);
        continue;
    }

    if(strpos($item, 'country.') !== false){
        $countries[]= substr($item,8);
       continue;
    }

    if(strpos($item, 'pm.') !== false){
        $pms[]= substr($item,3);
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split them.

something like this:

```
$arr = array("status" => [],"country" => [],"pm" => []);
foreach($data as $item){
    list($key,$val) = explode(".",$item);
    $arr[$key][] = $val;
}
extract($res); // taken from david's answer
```

and it's a much more readable code (in my opinion)

___ EDIT ____

as @DavidWinder commented, this is both not dynamic and will not result in different variables - look at [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914890/1670675) for the most complete solution for your question

Comment: Notice this ignore the OP request of: "I want each of them in separate variables" - add using extract in your answer (I tried to answer this more dynamically...)

Comment: @DavidWinder - correct, your's is the most complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Use [Explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). Also is a good way to use $limit param for performance and avoiding wrong behavior on having other '.' in values.

```
$arr = [];
foreach($data as $item){
    list($key,$val) = explode('.', $item, 2);
    if (!$key || !$val) continue;
    $arr[$key][] = $val;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll boost the performance but you could re-arrange your array in a way that each row has a heading and the corresponding value and then use `array_column()` to group which data you want.

This is an example of how you could group your data in such a way. (PHP 7.1.25+)

```
$groupedData = array_map(function($arg) {
    [$key, $val] = explode('.', $arg); # for PHP 5.6 < 7.1.25 use list($key, $val) = explode(...)
    return array($key => $val);
}, $data);
```

Then, you can pull out all of the country Id's like so:

```
$countries = array_column($groupedData, 'country');
```

Here is a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/rVQ2T).

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would do it like so...

```
<?php

$data = array ('status.1', 'status.2', 'status.3',
         'country.244', 'country.24', 'country.845',
         'pm.4', 'pm.9', 'pm.6');

$out = array ();

foreach ( $data AS $value )
{
    $value = explode ( '.', $value );

    $out[$value[0]][] = $value[1];
}

print_r ( $out );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push data into their respective groups while destructuring.  The only iterated function call is `explode()`.

[Creating individual variables for each group](https://3v4l.org/4lEqb) is a design flaw / mismanagement of array data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3XANg))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    [$prefix, $result[$prefix][]] = explode('.', $value, 2);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'status' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
    2 => '3',
  ),
  'country' => 
  array (
    0 => '244',
    1 => '24',
    2 => '845',
  ),
  'pm' => 
  array (
    0 => '4',
    1 => '9',
    2 => '6',
  ),
)
```

Use `sscanf()` if you want to directly/explicitly cast the numeric values as integers. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/5CN1i)