# Is there better way to split array by key starts with certain string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array for e.g.

```php
$myArray = [
    'id' => 1,
    'code' => '1234',
    'translation_lang_id' => 3,
    'translation_name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
    'translation_description' => 'My content'
];
```

Now I need to split it into: first with all keys & values where key starts with `translation_` and second with rest so it should finally looks like this:

```php
$translationArray = [
    'translation_lang_id' => 3,
    'translation_name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
    'translation_description' => 'My content'
];

$baseData = [
    'id' => 1,
    'code' => '1234',
];
```

Is there better way to do this than loop?

Comment: Related: [How to separate a php array items by prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914804/how-to-separate-a-php-array-items-by-prefix)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter` with the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag to separate the different elements according to whether the key starts with 'translation_' or not:

```
$translationArray = array_filter($myArray, 
                                 function ($k) { 
                                     return substr($k, 0, 12) == 'translation_'; 
                                 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$baseData = array_filter($myArray, 
                         function ($k) { 
                             return substr($k, 0, 12) != 'translation_'; 
                         }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_export($translationArray);
var_export($baseData);
```

Output:

```
array ( 
  'translation_lang_id' => 3,
  'translation_name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
  'translation_description' => 'My content', 
)
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'code' => '1234',
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fqsLZ)

Answer (score 3):

One brute force approach would be to just iterate your array, and assign elements to the appropriate destination array:

```
$translationArray = array();
$baseData = array();

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^translation_/", $key)) {
        $translationArray[$key] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $baseData[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pluck out the key values you want for one, and then difference the original array to get the other.

```
<?php

$input = [
    'id' => 1,
    'code' => '1234',
    'translation_lang_id' => 3,
    'translation_name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',
    'translation_description' => 'My content'
];

$translation = array_filter($input, function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'translation_') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$base = array_diff_key($input, $translation);

var_dump($translation, $base);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    ["translation_lang_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["translation_name"]=>
    string(11) "Lorem Ipsum"
    ["translation_description"]=>
    string(10) "My content"
  }
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["code"]=>
    string(4) "1234"
  }
```

But a loop is probably easier to read and follow:

```
foreach($input as $k=>$v)
    strpos($k, 'translation_') === 0 
        ? $translation[$k]=$v 
        : $base[$k]=$v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a efficient method but it just for the fun of it.
Here's a one liner :-)

```
$baseData = array_diff_key($myArray, $translationArray = array_intersect_key($myArray,array_flip(preg_grep("/^translation/", array_keys($myArray)))));
```

It uses preg_grep on the keys then matches them with array_intersect from the main array.
$baseData is then created as an array_diff_key from $translationArray.

https://3v4l.org/HE5vK

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Link**](https://3v4l.org/3K4IJ).

Search for any string replacing it with str and get the data in parts,

```
$str              = "translation_";
$len              = strlen($str); // upto length for fetching sub string
$translationArray = $baseData = [];
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, $len) == $str) { // checking here
        $translationArray[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $baseData[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```